# How to get folder permission to display with php

Tags: php

I know it is easy to see file permissions in php, but I can't find search reference for directory permissions.

Is is possible to display the folder permission and ownership with php?

If anyone can answer please also provide the example code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

PHP's [fileperms](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php) function also works with directories, as you can see in Example #2.

```
echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('/path/to/directory')), -4);
// prints something like 1777
```

Use [fileowner](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileowner.php) to get the ID of the user who owns the file/directory.

Comment: @user192344: The Windows usage is limited as it ignores the "group" and "other" parts of the mask. The permissions could also differ slightly.

Comment: so how to display user group and ownership for folder in linux

Comment: @user192344: Are you looking for an example of how to use `fileperms` or something else? I don't understand what you are asking. You can use `fileowner` to get the user's ID.

Comment: for posterity, `posix_getpwuid(fileowner($dir))` would information about the user once you have the file owner ID.

Answer (score 0):

Files and directories have the same nine `rwx` permission bits for owner, group, and all; they also have the same setuid, setgid, and sticky bits, but their meanings are different.

[`stat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) works the same on files and directories.